# Error relocating /usr/bin/node: _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev: symbol not found

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I'm trying to create Dockerfile based on **openjdk:8-alpine** with **nodejs 12.22.6-r0**

After installing nodejs I'm getting this error.

**Dockerfile** attached below.

Thanks in advance.

```
~ # node
Error relocating /usr/bin/node: _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/node: _ZNSt19_Sp_make_shared_tag5_S_eqERKSt9type_info: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/node: _ZNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev: symbol not found
```

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine

## install general tools
RUN apk update --no-cache && \
    apk add --no-cache \
    ca-certificates \
    openssh-client \
    libaio \
    net-tools \
    iputils \
    perl \
    bash \
    sed \
    zsh \
    vim \
    git \
    make \
    curl \
    wget \
    unzip \
    jq \
    procps \
    ttf-dejavu \ 
    python \
    ;


RUN apk add --no-cache \
    --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/ \
    nodejs=12.22.6-r0 \
    npm=12.22.6-r0 \
    ;
```

Comment: It seems likely that this is happening because the base image and its C++ libraries are one version, but you're trying to specifically use the Alpine 3.11 packaged version of Node and it requires a different version.  Can you use the version of Node from the `openjdk:8-alpine` image, removing the version pin and having just one `apk add` line with the default repository?  Or, there seems to be a _lot_ in this image; can you move the Node component to a separate image built `FROM node:12`?